# Is it unsafe to use `TaskAwaiter.GetResult()` method?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I read the "**C# 6.0 in a nutshell**" book by *J&B Albahari*. They use `TaskAwaiter.GetResult()` method in code, but I see in MSDN [this info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This API supports the product infrastructure and is not intended to be
>   used directly from your code.

Is it unsafe to use `TaskAwaiter.GetResult()` method?

Comment: Usually when you see this in the documentation, it means "you *could* use this, especially if your current task is to write a compiler, but there's probably a cleaner way for you to write your code that will not require you to call this method". Here, the obvious question would be why you're not just using `async`/`await`. Not having the book in question to hand, I can't answer for the authors - do they explain whether they're showing something about how things work "behind the scenes"?

Comment: I learn to work with the threads on the base of their book. They write some explanations but it is not clear for me sometimes.